# How to hotspot a resizable image?

Tags: html, css, resize

I would like to hotspot to areas in an image displayed on an html page. 
However this image changes width and height based on the display screen:

```
<img height="100%" width="100%" src="img.png"/>
```

How shall I hotspot it? 
I was thinking of a function that maps the original coordinates to those of the resized image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place the image and hotspots in a relatively positioned element and then position the hotspots absolutely using percentages:

**CSS**

```
.hotspotted {
    position: relative;
}

.hotspot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#hotspot1 {
   height: 81%;
   left: 9%;
   top: 16%;
   width: 45%;
}

#hotspot2{
    height: 18%; 
    right: 11%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 11%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hotspotted">
    <img height="100%" width="100%" src="img.png"/>
    <a href="#" id="hotspot1" class="hotspot"></a>
    <a href="#" id="hotspot2" class="hotspot"></a>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you are going to use a map then I suggest you calculate new co-ordinates rather than use percentages. This can be quite easily done using the following equation:

```
new_x = (orginal_x / original_image_width) * new_image_width
new_y = (orignal_y / original_image_height) * new_image_height
```

Comment: can you provide a complete example, with the <map> element?

Comment: @simpatico If you are using a map then don't use percentages - as far as I am aware they are not very well supported. You will just have to calculate new co-ordinates based on what you know about the image. I have updated my answer.

Comment: if not using a map, how do I get the hotspots to work? In your html code there are no links. Where do you put them?

Comment: @simpatico you can either replace the `span` elements with anchor elements or place the anchor elements within the `span` elements.

Comment: I tried both but I don't seem to get any working: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23278095/bert_html/hotspot.html

Comment: @simpatico you have to change the `height` and `width` of the hotspot to reflect the `height` and `width` of the part of the image you want to cover. If the elements are different sizes then set the `height` and `width` in the respective id styles instead. You will also have to change the `left` / `right` and `top` percentages to reflect where the images are on the page.

Comment: but there we are back to the origin. I don't know the "the height and width of the hotspot to reflect the height and width of the part of the image you want to cover." They change depending on the display.

Comment: @simpatico If you know that the height of the hotspotted area is 30% of the height of your image then you set the height to 30% and the same goes for width. For example, if the height of your image was originally 100px and the height of the hotspotted area on that original picture was 30px then you set the height to 30%. I have updated my answer so `#hotspot1` directly represents what you need to do in the link you added in the comments above. Hopefully you can use that help you work out what you need to do for `#hotspot2`!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert coordinates (x,y) to percentage.

E.g. if your image is 200px width and 200px height, and your coordinates are x=50px,y=100px then after converting you get

```
x = 50/200*100 = 25%
y = 100/200*100 = 50%
```

So now you know that your coordinates are always 25% from left of the screen and 50% from top, assuming that image takes whole screen. Is this what you were asking? :)