# Position Hotspots on Scaleable Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image with hotspots that works fine if I assign the image a definite width and height. If I make the image scaleable using width=100%, then while my hotspot 'left'/'width' positioning stays accurate, the 'top'/'height' position moves all over the place. I know I need to set my top/height position by basing it on a measure of the current screen width, I just don't have the knowledge/language of how to code that.

This is the coding that works when the image is at original size (width 1580, height 1050), and so if i could just code my top to be top= 93% * (1050 / 1580) * new_screen_width BUT!

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample Photo</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.hotspotted {
    position: relative;
}

.hotspot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#hotspot1 {
    height: 8%;
    left: 87%;
    top: 85%;
    width: 13%;
}

#hotspot2 {
    height: 7%;
    left: 92%;
    top: 93%;
    width: 4%;
}

#hotspot3 {
    height: 7%;
    left: 96%;
    top: 93%;
    width: 4%;
}



</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="hot spotted">
<img src="images/homepage D.jpg" width="100%"  /> 
<a href="DMD A.html" id="hotspot1" class="hotspot"></a> 
<a href="DMD C.html" id="hotspot2" class="hotspot"></a> 
<a href="index.html" id="hotspot3" class="hotspot"></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like there's an error in css - not .hotspotted, but .hot.spotted.

Answer (score 1):

This answer should be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411956/1825150

> You could place the image and hotspots in a relatively positioned element and then position the hotspots absolutely using percentages...

Check out that answer, [My Head Hurts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681807/my-head-hurts) gives a detailed example as well. Hope this helps.

Edit: As per comments from Vality and Ghost, here's the quote of what that linked answer provides (at the time of this edit):

Important Note: The content of the linked answer comes from the poster mentioned above.

## CSS

```
.hotspotted {
    position: relative;
}

.hotspot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#hotspot1 {
   height: 81%;
   left: 9%;
   top: 16%;
   width: 45%;
}

#hotspot2{
    height: 18%; 
    right: 11%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 11%;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="hotspotted">
        <img height="100%" width="100%" src="img.png"/>
        <a href="#" id="hotspot1" class="hotspot"></a>
        <a href="#" id="hotspot2" class="hotspot"></a>
</div>
```

## OP's UPDATE

> If you are going to use a map then I suggest you calculate new co-ordinates rather than use percentages. This can be quite easily done using the following equation:

```
new_x = (orginal_x / original_image_width) * new_image_width
new_y = (orignal_y / original_image_height) * new_image_height
```

Comment: Please try and copy some of the answer from the link into your answer as otherwise if the link goes dead nobody will know your solution. Still, welcome to SO and well done on an otherwise good answer.