# creating scaleable responsive hotpoints

Tags: html, css

Im going off this tutorial / question here

[How to hotspot a resizable image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411793/how-to-hotspot-a-resizable-image/11411956#11411956)

Im trying to resize hotpoints for mobile.

Here is my code for CSS

```
<style>
.hotspotted {
position: relative;
}

.hotspot {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}

#hotspot1 {
height: 81%;
left: 9%;
top: 16%;
width: 45%;
}

#hotspot2{
height: 15%; 
left: 16%;
top: -5%;
width: 11%;
background-color:#0F6
}

img {max-width:100%}

body {
background-color: #069;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div class="hotspotted">
<img src="sv-map.png" border="0"/>
<a href="#" id="hotspot1" class="hotspot"></a>
<a href="www.google.co.nz" id="hotspot2" class="hotspot"></a>
</div>
```

now Im trying to create or use these hotpoints on the following map

[image]

but with no luck on the responsive side of things.

I noticed in the other link that My Head Hurts answered that you need to use coordinates. I wouldnt know where to begin and was hoping someone could give me a hand on this

Thanks

Comment: anybody know what could be done?

Comment: Take a look at this [Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) - it might be of help ([working example](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html))

Comment: Thank you My Head Hurts - Will give this a go

Comment: Hi My Head Hurts - This worked but not for mobile. Do you know if there is a way to get it working for mobile?

Comment: It works, to a certain extent.. It is responsive however for mobile it doesnt work.