# Click position for different screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a project in which when a user clicks at a specific area of the image, a dot is placed in that position, but when the screen size or height changes, the click position of that area also changes. But my algorithm is calculating the dot position based on the previous click position. Now I need to know the amount of pixel change and calculate the new click position that will point to the same area on which the user had clicked previously.Here is a code to calculate the position of the clicked area. **Note: the height of the image is always equal to the view port height**

```
$(".largeimage").on("click", function(event) {
    var offset = $('.hotspot-inner').offset(),
          relativeX = event.pageX - offset.left,
          relativeY = event.pageY - offset.top;
      var height = $('.largeimage').height(),
          width = $('.largeimage').width();
      let hotspot = {
        x: relativeX / width * 100,
        y: relativeY / height * 100
      }
    console.log(hotspot)
});
```

and here is the code to display the dot.

```
var height = $('.largeimage').height(),
    width = $('.largeimage').width(),
    offset = $('.largeimage').offset(),
    parent_offset = $('.hotspot-inner').offset();
$(".info-icon-1").css({
  'top': hotspot.y * height / 100 + (offset.top - parent_offset.top) + 'px',
  'left': hotspot.x * width / 100 + (offset.left - parent_offset.left) + 'px'
})
```

structure of the html

```
<div class="hotspot-container">
  <div class="hotspot-inner" id="hotspot-manger">
    <img src="imgs/arrow1.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon-1" data-target="pop1" data-x="38.19791714350382" data-y="45.84487534626039">
    <img src="imgs/large_image.png" alt="butifull image" class="largeimage">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a video version of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15S6ubcWJirR1vtUFHUpePifSFHzykeAG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hotspot a resizable image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411793/how-to-hotspot-a-resizable-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working responsively, don't use pixels, always use ratios and percentages based on current element dimensions.

See resizable example image demo below, click to save pointer image and then resize...

jsFiddle version... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/tfo9mheL/

```js
$('.hotspot-img').on('click', function(e) {
  var offset        = $(this).offset(),
        relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left,
        relativeY = e.pageY - offset.top;
  var height        = $(this).height(),
        width       = $(this).width();
  let hotspot = {
    x: relativeX / width * 100,
    y: relativeY / height * 100
  }
  $(this).next('.hotspot-icon').css({
    'display'   : 'block',
    'top'           : hotspot.y + '%',
    'left'      : hotspot.x + '%'
  });
});
```

```css
HTML, BODY {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hotspot {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hotspot:hover {
  cursor: url('https://i.imgur.com/HxpSuX7.png') 60 41, auto;
}

.hotspot-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hotspot-icon {
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hotspot">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jiImOV4.jpg" class="hotspot-img "/>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HxpSuX7.png" class="hotspot-icon "/>
</div>

<p style="text-align:right;">Resize image to emulate responsive changes &#94;</p>
```

---

### Update 1

Here is a version where the `hotspot-img` is set to `height: 100vh;`. The `hotspot` div is then centred on the `X` axis using position `left` and translate-x `-50%`...

jsFiddle version... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/3jf6mspt/

```js
$('.hotspot-img').on('click', function(e) {
  var offset        = $(this).offset(),
        relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left,
        relativeY = e.pageY - offset.top;
  var height        = $(this).height(),
        width       = $(this).width();
  let hotspot = {
    x: relativeX / width * 100,
    y: relativeY / height * 100
  }
  $(this).next('.hotspot-icon').css({
    'display'   : 'block',
    'top'           : hotspot.y + '%',
    'left'      : hotspot.x + '%'
  });
});
```

```css
HTML, BODY {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hotspot {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.hotspot:hover {
  cursor: url('https://i.imgur.com/HxpSuX7.png') 60 41, auto;
}

.hotspot-img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hotspot-icon {
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hotspot">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jiImOV4.jpg" class="hotspot-img "/>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HxpSuX7.png" class="hotspot-icon "/>
</div>
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

> Question for you, are you trying to achieve this but for an image that
> covers your entire viewport? For example like how css
> `background-size: cover;` works?

Comment: Hi joshmoto!
Thank you for your solution, but one thing I forgot to mention is that the height of the image will always be equal to the viewport of the device. So would you please provide a solution for that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @KamranSiddique see `Update 1` solution for full viewport height in my answer. Let me know if this works or if you need fullscreen cover image solution?

Comment: @KamranSiddique i've just seen your google drive video, I will look into a solution for this